# Handling a C# method that isn't defined on a dynamic object (aka respond_to/method_missing)

Tags: dynamic, c#-4.0

Given the new dynamic support in C# 4, is it possible to write a class in such a way that if a method is invoked on an instance and that method is not present, dispatch is passed to another method? This might look something like:

```
public class Apple : ... {
  // ...

  private ... MethodMissing(string name, ...) {
    if (name == "TurnIntoOrange") {
      // do something
    }
  }
}

dynamic d = new Apple();
d.TurnIntoOrange();       // Not actually defined on Apple; will pass to MethodMissing.
```

Other languages would call this "method_missing support", under the more general heading of metaprogramming. I'm not sure what C# calls this specifically. But is it possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Absolutely. Either implement [`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider(VS.100).aspx) or derive from [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(VS.100).aspx) for a much simpler route. See the [DLR documentation](http://dlr.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Docs%20and%20specs) for some good examples.

Here's a quick example of `DynamicObject`:

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;

public class MyDynamic : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryInvokeMember
        (InvokeMemberBinder binder,
         object[] args,
         out object result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I would have invoked: {0}",
                          binder.Name);
        result = "dummy";
        return true;
    }

    public string NormalMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In NormalMethod");
        return "normal";
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        dynamic d = new MyDynamic();
        Console.WriteLine(d.HelloWorld());
        Console.WriteLine(d.NormalMethod());
    }
}
```

**`<plug>`**

I have a bigger example of `DynamicObject` in the [2nd edition of C# in Depth](http://manning.com/skeet2) but I haven't yet implemented `IDyamicMetaObjectProvider`. I'll do so before the book's release, but the early access edition only has the `DynamicObject` example at the moment. Btw, if you buy it today it's half price - use the code **twtr0711**. I'll edit this answer later on to remove that bit :)

**`</plug>`**

Comment: I alluded to this in my title but didn't directly ask it in the body: Is there a similar override I'd use to mimic a "responds_to" method.? I see that I can check the result of TryInvokeMember, but that might result in undesirable side effects.

Comment: No, I don't believe there's any way of asking a dynamic method whether it will handle anything - although you could call GetDynamicMemberNames as a starting point.

Comment: GetDynamicMemberNames() is an optional thing, i.e. a class inheriting from DynamicObject can override it if it wants, but if it doesn't the function in the base class gets called which returns an empty list.