# Intercept a dynamic call to avoid RuntimeBinderException

Tags: c#, dynamic, runtimeexception

I want to intercept calls to a dynamic type to avoid a RuntimeBinderException when the method or property called does not exist.
For example:

```
class Foo {
    bool IsFool{ get; set; }
}
...
dynamic d = new Foo();
bool isFool = d.IsFoo; //works fine
bool isSpecial = d.IsSpecial; //RuntimeBinderException
```

What I want to do is to either create the nonexistent property when called or to just return null.

**EDIT**: The project I'm trying to do is a configuration file reader. So I want this to avoid doing a try catch or check if exists to every property of the cofiguration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1110504/818088
I have to extend the `DynamicObject` and override `TryInvokeMember`

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any special way than handling in `try .. catch` block like

```
try 
{
  bool isSpecial = d.IsSpecial;
  return isSpecial;
}
catch(RuntimeBinderException)
{
  // do something else
  return false;
}
```

(OR) Using `System.Reflection` namespace

```
        bool isSpecial = typeof(Foo)
                         .GetProperties()
                         .Select(p => p.Name == "IsSpecial").Count() > 0 
                         ? d.IsSpecial : false;
```

Per your edit in post; not sure how elegant this would be but you can define a `AppSetting` element in `App.Config` or `Web.Config` file like

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="IsFool" value="Foo"/>
    <add key="Display" value="Foo"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then can read that to verify whether the member exists or not and then call accordingly

```
        dynamic d = new Foo();

        bool isSpecial = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
                         .AllKeys.Contains("IsSpecial") 
                         ? d.IsSpecial : false;
```

Comment: Thank you, but this way defeats the main purpose which is to make the code easier to write and read.

Comment: @dcidral, have suggested two choices; either use `try .. catch` block or using Reflection. See edit in answer.

Comment: @dcidral, check edit in answer if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi @rahul . I apreciate your help and I'm sorry to not be more clear. I have no issues reading the configuration file in a variety of ways. What I want to create is a project to make this process more clean and easy to use in several other projects. So the issue is about intercepting a call to a dynamic variable. To read the configuration file I already have a class that uses something like: var configValue = config["config_name"].Value; but I want to do something like this: var configValue = config.config_name;

Answer (score 1):

Exception usualy take much time try to check if property exist:

```
public static bool HasProperty(this object obj, string propertyName)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName) != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to convert it into a JSON dynamic object:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static dynamic ToJson(this object input) => 
         System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(input));

    static int Main(string[] args) {
         dynamic d = new Foo() { IsFool = true }.ToJson();
         Console.WriteLine(d.IsFool); //prints True
         Console.WriteLine(d.IsSpecial ?? "null"); //prints null
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public bool IsFool { get; set; }
}
```