# Lambda Expression on Extension Method to Get Only Properties from Object

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I am writing a small validation fluent API for validating commands which I am using in the following way:

```
Validator.Candidate(foo).Verify(x => x.Name).IsNotNull();
```

Effectively, the verify method passes the value of the lambda expression (in this case a string extracted from the `foo.Name` property) to a set of extension methods, for example `IsNotNull()`, `IsGreaterThan(10)` etc. The extension methods can then raise errors if needed and so on.

The underlying classes and extension methods used in the API are:

```
public static class Validator
{
    public static ValidationCandidate<T> Candidate<T>(T candidate)
    {
        return new ValidationCandidate<T>(candidate);
    }
}

public class ValidationCandidate<T> : IValidatorCandidate<T>
{
    public ValidationCandidate(T candidate)
    {
        Object = candidate;
    }

    public T Object { get; private set; }
}

public class ValidatorProperty<TCommand, TProperty> : IValidatorProperty
{
    public static ValidatorProperty<TCommand, TProperty> Verify<TCommand, TProperty>(this IValidatorCandidate<TCommand> candidate, Expression<Func<TCommand>> func)
    {     
       return new ValidatorProperty<TCommand, TProperty>(candidate, func.Invoke(candidate.Object), name);
    }
}

public class ValidatorProperty<TCommand, TProperty> : IValidatorProperty
{
   public ValidatorProperty(IValidatorCandidate<TCommand> candidate, TProperty value, string name) {
   }

   public TProperty Value { get; private set; } 
   public IValidatorCandidate<TCommand> Candidate { get; private set; }
}
```

The `IsNotNull()` extension show above is not important and unrelated to the problem at hand.

The problem is that in the `Verify()` method I am passing a lambda to select a property of the object used in `Candidate()`.

What I want to be able to do is restrict the lambda used in `Verify()` to only allow properties of the candidate object to be passed in, i.e. if the candidate object is defined as:

```
public Foo() {
   string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to do:

```
Validator.Object(instanceOfFoo).Verify(x => x.Name).....
```

but NOT:

```
Validator.Object(instanceOfFoo).Verify(x => "Hello")....
```

At the moment both usages above will compile. I think this is because I have written the signature for the lamda in `Verify` incorrectly for what I want to do and don't know how to write it to do what I want it to!

The lambda needs to be written in such as what that if an attempt is made to pass something into `Verify` that is not a property of Foo (or whatever object is being used as the candidate object) then a compiler error is thrown.  I don't want to do the check at runtime.

Comment: Maybe the dynamic library is for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110481/handling-a-c-sharp-method-that-isnt-defined-on-a-dynamic-object-aka-respond-to/1110504#1110504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to express that constraint in C#, and therefore there is no way for the compiler to check it at compile time.

However, you can catch it before runtime by using static code analysis. The easiest way for you to do that is probably to use Roslyn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx

This way, you can give immediate feedback to the developer, and catch any errors at buildtime.